# Feature scaling and its affect on various algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Despite going through lots of similar question related to this I still could not understand why some algorithm is susceptible to it while others are not.

Till now I found that SVM and K-means are susceptible to feature scaling while Linear Regression and Decision Tree are not.Can somebody please elaborate me why? in general or relating to this 4 algorithm.

As I am a beginner, please explain this in layman terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason I can think of off-hand is that SVM and K-means, at least with a basic configuration, uses an L2 distance metric. An L1 or L2 distance metric between two points will give different results if you double delta-x or delta-y, for example.

With Linear Regression, you fit a linear transform to best describe the data by effectively transforming the coordinate system before taking a measurement. Since the optimal model is the same no matter the coordinate system of the data, pretty much by definition, your result will be invariant to any linear transform including feature scaling.

With Decision Trees, you typically look for rules of the form x < N, where the only detail that matters is how many items pass or fail the given threshold test - you pass this into your entropy function. Because this rule format does not depend on dimension scale, since there is no continuous distance metric, we again have in-variance.

Somewhat different reasons for each, but I hope that helps.